# How to get the current path with symlink (not the actual path) in a c program on a linux system?

Tags: c, linux, symlink, pwd, getcwd

I am currently building a custom shell that can handle a few internal and external commands along with their options. One of these internal commands is `pwd`. From the [man page of pwd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pwd.1.html#:%7E:text=even%20if%20it%20contains%20symlinks), I got that `pwd -L` is going to output the current working directory even if it contains symlinks.

Now for implementing this, I want to know what functionality is available in C that can provide the working directory without resolving symlinks.

OS: GNU/Linux

PS: `getcwd()` gives the actual path [and resolves the symlink.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getcwd.html#:%7E:text=The%20pathname%20shall%20contain%20no%20components%20that%20are%20dot%20or%20dot%2Ddot%2C%20or%20are%20symbolic%20links.) (Correct me if I am wrong somewhere).

Comment: I do not understand - you want to have the path some symlink points to or you want to resolve all symlinks in a path? I.e. you want realpath() or readlinke() ?

Comment: @KamilCuk In simple words, I want one with symlinks.(i.e. not resolve them)

Comment: The current working directory is like always the one without symlinks. It seems to me that _you_ have to store the one with symlinks in your program and manage it youself.

Comment: I see... By the way, is that also how it is implemented in the default bash shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pwd` command has 2 different modes:

- `pwd -L` displays the *logical* current working directory.
- `pwd -P` displays the *physical* current working directory (all symbolic links resolved).

If no options are specified, the -L option is assumed.

`pwd -P` uses the `getcwd()` function: it resolves the `..` chain from the current directory of the process.

Starting from the current directory, whose inode and device number are retrieved, it opens the parent directory as with `opendir("..")` and enumerates the entries until one is found with the same inode and device number. This entry is the last component of the current directory name. If no such entry is found, `getcwd()` fails and sets `errno` to `ENOENT`.

The process keeps going on the next parent directory until the root directory is reached.

This is very inefficient. `pwd -L`, which is the default, uses a different method: the shell maintains an environment variable `PWD` that contains the unresolved path to the current directory as reached by the shell via `chdir`/`cd` commands. This path may differ from that obtained by `getcwd()` if symbolic links were followed to reach the current directory or if some parts of the path have been renamed, moved or even removed. Thus the path stored in `$PWD` may not even exist anymore, or may lead to a different place.

To implement `pwd -L` in your shell, you can just output the value of the `PWD` environment variable, and you should update this variable when you execute `chdir` / `cd` shell commands.

Note also that for this `chdir` / `cd` command, paths relative to the current directory should be *resolved* logically relative to this unresolved path by dropping the previous component for each `../` in the destination path. Only the resulting string that contains no `.` or `..` component is passed to the OS via the `chdir` system call.

Comment: So basically I can get the value of the `PWD` variable using `getenv()`, and that will give me the same output that I would have gotten by executing the `pwd` command in the shell..?

Comment: @AspectKarlos: yes and the `PWD` variable must be properly maintained as a side effect of the `cd` / `chdir` shell commands. I updated the answer with more gory details about this.